# How to use encrypted swap with systemd?

Tags: centos, systemd, encryption, swap

I am using CentOS 7. I created `/etc/crypttab` with the line

`cryptswap    /swap   /dev/urandom    swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,nofail`

and `/etc/fstab` with the line

`/dev/mapper/cryptswap              none    swap    sw,nofail   0   0`

After creating the swap file with

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=4M count=200`

I get the error messages

`systemd-cryptsetup[512]: Failed to activate with key file '/dev/urandom': Operation not supported`

and

`systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-cryptswap.device.`

`systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Cryptography Setup for cryptswap.`

`systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/mapper/cryptswap.`

at reboot.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly to reiterate `/dev/urandom` is supported and recommended by the [crypttab documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crypttab).

> For swap encryption /dev/urandom can be used as the password file; using  /dev/random may prevent boot completion if the system does not have enough entropy to generate a truly random encryption key.

You need to create the device on which the swap will reside, `/dev/mapper/cryptswap` and format it as a swap area.

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=4M count=200
# cryptsetup luksFormat /swap
```

The password here does not matter as long as it passes the check

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen /swap cryptswap
```

This will create `/dev/mapper/cryptswap` which is what you will use for the swap partition

```
# mkswap /dev/mapper/cryptswap
```

In `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap           none    swap    defaults        0 0
```

To activate

```
# swapon -a
```

To confirm

```
# cat /proc/swaps
```

or

```
# swapon -s
```

Note: you will see the device to which `/dev/mapper/cryptswap` is linked in the ouput of these commands

```
# ls -l /dev/mapper/cryptswap
```